# Damaged Switching Regulator

Tags: buck, 12v, damage

I am working on turning on a board of mine on which I am attempting to use a TI [TPS563208](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps563208) switching regulator. I believe I have followed the typical application in implementing this regulator in my conversion of 12V to 3.3V (see schematic below), but I have now damaged two parts in the exact same manor and I'm struggling to understand why. During my initial testing I had powered it with my bench top supply set to 12V with a low current limit. As soon as I power up the 12V supply I noticed the current reading shoot up and then the output regulation of the TPS563208 dropped out to nearly zero. At this point measured as much as I could and found that the SW output now had a reading of only about 3 Ohms to ground. Before powering the system up I was reading 70 Ohms (this seems reasonable for the load on my supply).

At this point I pulled the dead TPS563208 and made sure I didn't have any shorts on my board (either from assembly or manufacturing defects). I walked through the entire design checking for anything that didn't match my schematic and found none. I do not believe the problem lies with the 12V side as without U5 in the schematic my 12V draws basically no current, and I can manually supply 3.3V to the downstream circuitry from the bench supply without issues. Once I confirmed that nothing was physically wrong, I put a spare part back on the board, added an electrolytic cap to the input (in attempts to possibly reduce overvoltage spikes on power up (as described in linear's AN88 app note), and this time set my bench supply to 6V. Powering this up appeared to work! I did notice I was getting some drift on my output voltage, but it was regulating and drawing approximately the amount of current I expected for my load. From here I increased the input voltage to 9V and it again appeared to work. Unfortunately though, once I set it back to my desired 12V, the output voltage came up at 3.3V, quickly increased, and then dropped out and the impedance to ground on the SW output again read nearly zero. It was toast.

I've looked over the recommended layout and compared it to mine and see I could make some serious improvements, but what I want to understand is if this is something that could be caused simply by bad layout? I'm going to do another revision of the board, so I can cleanup the layout but if I have some other problem I'd like to understand now to reduce the chance of having to do a third rev of the board.

Hopefully you guys can help! I've put down a few other buck converters in the past and didn't have any issues then, but I'm admittedly a bit rusty.

[image: tps563208 schematic]

Comment: Make sure your footprint is correct and not mirrored or something silly. Ensure R17 and R15 aren't swapped and you get a reasonable value at VFB when 3.3V is on the 3.3V rail. (with the chip removed)

Comment: Part of the problem with my layout is the fact that I have the wrong footprint (footprint is too large), so I've had to deadbug it a bit to get it meet the pins. But, the pins should match (IE pad 1 goes to pin 1, etc) I've checked the two feedback resistors and they appear to be the correct value and when I supply an external voltage I'm getting ~0.8V which seems about right. I did notice that before I killed the second one (6V & 9V), that even putting my finger on the part to check temp I saw the regulation go a bit haywire.

Comment: This makes me suspect my feedback loop has a problem, but unfortunately the part died before I had a chance to probe much with an oscilloscope. Though, if that was the case, I'm still not sure how/why the part might die do to an unstable feedback loop.

Comment: How much load is the regulator driving? Is it sufficiently heat-sunk when dead-bugged?

Comment: Can you get it to power up into a minimal or no load on the 3.3V rail?

Comment: It woudn't take much stray inductance to cause enough spikes to kill the chip. Are your dead bug wires really short? Especially pins 1 & 3.

Comment: About 100mA currently (when powered externally with a bench supply).

Comment: @Sephro My dead bug wires to the left side are pretty short as I placed the part close to those and then ran wires over the other side. Unfortunately though this means VFB and VBST both have pretty long wires.

@ ThreePhaseEel I can't really disconnect the IC from the load easily and to top it off, I used up all my spare parts, so I need to order more...